# relational database design structure for a specific query

Tags: sql, database

I have a database problem where I am suppose to design a tour database. they keep track
visitors, tickets,  and  the attractions  (such  as  palace or  local shows)  that  they  visit.  We  assume  that  each  visitor  has  to  buy  a  ticket  to  enter  the  tour.

Each  ticket  is  valid  for  only  one  day,  and  there  are  no  special  tickets  for  children  or  families  etc.  But  there  are   several  classes  of  tickets,  in  particular  Gold,  Silver,  and  Bronze  tickets.  A  Gold  ticket  is  more  expensive,  but  then  most  of  the  attractions  in  the  tour  are  free  or
at  least  fairly  cheap.  For  Silver  and  Bronze  tickets,  there  may  be  significant  extra  charges  for  most  of  the  attractions.  Thus,  a  person  planning  to  spend  the  whole  day  and  do  as  many  rides  as  possible  may  want  to  buy  a  Gold  ticket,  while  others  are  better off  with  a  Silver  or  Bronze  ticket.

Ticket  prices,  as  well  as  the  extra  charges  per  attraction  for  each  ticket  class,  may  depend  on  the  season,  and  may  change  over  time.  Thus,  during  Spring  Break  2013  Season  there  may  be  one  set  of  prices,  while  during  the  Peak  Summer  Season  2013  there  may  be  another set  of  prices.  Each  attraction  has   a   unique   name   (e.g.,    Glass museum  or  gold mine),   and   whenever   a   visitor   visits   an  attraction,  the  database should  store  information  about  the  ticket  held  by  the  visitor  and  about  when  exactly  the  visitor  entered  the  attraction.

```
Visitors
(v_id,visitor_name)

Ticket_purchase
(v_id,t_id,date)

Tickets
(t_id,class,price,season)

Attractions
(t_id,attraction_name,goldextracost,silverextracost,bronzeextracost)

Attraction_visited
(v_id,t_id,attraction_name,datetime)
```

Now if I want to output the number of people who bought a Bronze ticket but who would have saved money if they had bought a Gold ticket (because they visited a lot of attractions where they had to pay extra during that day)

Is it possible with the above tables or I need some structural changes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the information you need. You're recording the ticket used when a patron visits an attraction and with that data you can get the ticket class and calculate what the cost would have been had they visited the attraction with a different class ticket.

Answer (score 0):

from what i can see you overwrite the ticket price when you change it... 
because of this you cannot look back at different ticket prices... as i undrstand ticket prices can change 
you would have to add to the tickets a field for the date when you created the new price. then you would not delete the old ticket price. just pull the newest.
and the same for anything else with a price... you cant overwrite it.. just add a start date...

and when you are ready to see how much the person spend you can see how much they spent on their tickets and attractions...

once you do this what you want will be possible.

Comment: Right now I have fixed set of tickets. I mean I don't generate different ticket for each visitor. Its like Ticket id 1 with class gold season spring 2013 has base cost 40 and same way for silver and bronze. I have done it for most of the seasons and not included date. But I think I will have to.

Comment: yes but if bronze ticket in 2013 is $40 and bronze in 2014 in $50 you will have to have a startDate for each ticket price.
ex. Attractions
(t_id,attraction_name,goldextracost,silverextracost,bronzeextracost,startDate)

Comment: wait i may be wrong about how i understand your structure
it also seems like you can also combine ticket purchase and tickets...
i am having a hard time understanding your structure.. can you please try and explain it a little better?

Comment: Well for every season eg fall13,fall14 I just add new entry in the ticket table. I know it won't be fruitful in long run. But I didn't think to normalize it yet. So there are two prices a base price which changes every season and is recorded in Ticket table while the extra cost for each attraction is stored in attraction table as per class. I have assumed right now that only base cost changes and  extra cost remains fixed.